# AVCaptureStillImageOutput never calls completition handler

Tags: ios, camera, avfoundation, video-capture

Following code doesn't work. Whats wrong?

```
AVCaptureDevice * videoDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
AVCaptureDeviceInput * videoInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:videoDevice error:nil];
AVCaptureSession * captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium;
if (![captureSession canAddInput:videoInput])
    NSLog(@"Can't add input");
[captureSession addInput:videoInput];

self.stillImageOutput = [[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc] init];
[self.stillImageOutput setOutputSettings:@{AVVideoCodecKey:AVVideoCodecJPEG}];
if (![captureSession canAddOutput:videoInput])
    NSLog(@"Can't add output");
[captureSession addOutput:self.stillImageOutput];

[self.stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:[self.stillImageOutput.connections lastObject]
                                                   completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageDataSampleBuffer, NSError *error)
                                                   {
                                                       NSLog(@"!!!");

                                                       if (imageDataSampleBuffer == NULL)
                                                       {
                                                           NSLog(@"%@", error);
                                                           return;
                                                       }

                                                       NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageDataSampleBuffer];
                                                       UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
                                                       self.imageView.image = image;
                                                   }];

// Creating preview layer
self.previewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:captureSession];
self.previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
self.previewLayer.frame = self.view.layer.bounds;
[self.view.layer addSublayer:self.previewLayer];

[captureSession startRunning];
```

AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer works nice, but AVCaptureStillImageOutput does not call completion handler at all...

Answer (score 2):

You need to set up & start your session in one method,
then have a separate capture method :

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////
////
//// Utility to find front camera
////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////
-(AVCaptureDevice *) frontFacingCameraIfAvailable{

    NSArray *videoDevices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    AVCaptureDevice *captureDevice = nil;

   for (AVCaptureDevice *device in videoDevices){

        if (device.position == AVCaptureDevicePositionFront){

            captureDevice = device;
            break;
        }
    }

    //  couldn't find one on the front, so just get the default video device.
    if (!captureDevice){

        captureDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    }

    return captureDevice;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////
////
//// Setup Session, attach Video Preview Layer
//// and Capture Device, start running session
////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////
-(void) setupCaptureSession {
    AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium;

    AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *captureVideoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer    alloc] initWithSession:session];
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:captureVideoPreviewLayer];

    NSError *error = nil;
    AVCaptureDevice *device = [self frontFacingCameraIfAvailable];
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:&error];
    if (!input) {
        // Handle the error appropriately.
        NSLog(@"ERROR: trying to open camera: %@", error);
    }
    [session addInput:input];

    self.stillImageOutput = [[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *outputSettings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: AVVideoCodecJPEG, AVVideoCodecKey, nil];
    [self.stillImageOutput setOutputSettings:outputSettings];

    [session addOutput:self.stillImageOutput];

    [session startRunning];
}


/////////////////////////////////////////////////
////
//// Method to capture Still Image from 
//// Video Preview Layer
////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////
-(void) captureNow {
    AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = nil;
    for (AVCaptureConnection *connection in self.stillImageOutput.connections) {
        for (AVCaptureInputPort *port in [connection inputPorts]) {
            if ([[port mediaType] isEqual:AVMediaTypeVideo] ) {
                videoConnection = connection;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (videoConnection) { break; }
    }

    NSLog(@"about to request a capture from: %@", self.stillImageOutput);
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    [self.stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection completionHandler: ^(CMSampleBufferRef imageSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {

         NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageSampleBuffer];
         UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];

         [weakSelf displayImage:image];
     }];
}
```

Comment: The only reason "doing it in separate methods" solves this problem, is that it has the side-effect of retaining AVCaptureSession in the controller.

I think there's a bug in AVCaptureStillImageOutput that makes it lose track of its AVCaptureSession in automatic-reference-counting mode.

Comment: Ah, good point. Yeah - a colleague & I were trying to get it to work the way you are trying last Friday, but had no luck. I was up until the wee hours of the morning, and found it best to initialize AVCaptureSession separately. Best of Luck!

Comment: I am trying to do the same in swift but it is not working.....is there a reason why wouldnt it work..I have the same code....

Comment: In my case stillImageOutput.connections was nil because i was allocating AVCaptureSession and AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer twice, so just added check whether session == nil then only do [[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc] init] and all stillImageOutput preset

Answer (score 1):

This works well:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    AVCaptureDevice * videoDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    AVCaptureDeviceInput * videoInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:videoDevice error:nil];
    AVCaptureSession * captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium;
    [captureSession addInput:videoInput];
    [captureSession addOutput:self.stillImageOutput];
    [captureSession startRunning];

    // Creating preview layer
    self.previewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:captureSession];
    self.previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
    self.previewLayer.frame = self.view.layer.bounds;
    [self.view.layer insertSublayer:self.previewLayer atIndex:0];
}

- (void)timerFired:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    [self.stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:[self.stillImageOutput.connections lastObject]
                                                       completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageDataSampleBuffer, NSError *error)
                                                       {
                                                           NSLog(@"!!!");

                                                           if (imageDataSampleBuffer == NULL)
                                                               NSLog(@"%@", error);

                                                           NSData * imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageDataSampleBuffer];
                                                           UIImage * image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
                                                           self.imageView.image = image;
                                                       }];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(timerFired:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```