# Why AVCaptureStillImageOutput ::captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:completionHandler is never called?

Tags: iphone, ios, avfoundation, capture

I try to build an app which captures frames from iPhone camera and does some processing with these frames. I tried some pieces of codes found on the Internet, e.g. here: [How to capture image without displaying preview in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10053197/how-to-capture-image-without-displaying-preview-in-ios)

and I ended up with the following piece of code:

```
-(IBAction)captureNow{
    AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = nil;
    for (AVCaptureConnection *connection in stillImageOutput.connections)
    {
        for (AVCaptureInputPort *port in [connection inputPorts])
        {
            if ([[port mediaType] isEqual:AVMediaTypeVideo] )
            {
                videoConnection = connection;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (videoConnection) { break; }
    }

    //  NSLog(@"about to request a capture from: %@", stillImageOutput);
    [stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection completionHandler: ^(CMSampleBufferRef imageSampleBuffer, NSError *error)
     {
         CFDictionaryRef exifAttachments = CMGetAttachment( imageSampleBuffer, kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary, NULL);
         if (exifAttachments)
         {
             // Do something with the attachments.
             NSLog(@"attachements: %@", exifAttachments);
         }
         else
             NSLog(@"no attachments");

         NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageSampleBuffer];
         UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];

         //  do the processing with the image       
         }
```

However, the app never gets into the handler code block of the captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection method so I never get the image from the frame.
Am I doing something in a wrong way? 
Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: You might check if your `AVCaptureSession` is still running. If you end it to early, your completionHandler never gets called.

Answer (score 8):

I've discovered that the pointer to `AVCaptureSession` doesn't get retained properly by `AVCaptureStillImageOutput` in Automatic-Reference-Counting mode.

This means you have two options:

- [disable automatic reference counting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7778356/how-to-enable-disable-automatic-reference-counting), or
- retain the pointer to `AVCaptureSession` yourself (for example, by assigning it to a strong property in your controller).

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check the `NSError` *error parameter. It gives you information about the picture being successfully taken. `AVFoundation` error codes are [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundation_ErrorConstants/Reference/reference.html). I hope this helps.

Also you might want to read about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12445403/avcapturestillimageoutput-never-calls-completition-handler), where he explains having session code at same place could lead to problems.